# Upload doc, pdf,xls etc, from android application to php server

Tags: php, android, pdf, file-upload

I get stuck at that place and unable to send doc file to php server. 
I am using this code.

Here is PHP code.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $image = $_POST['image'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql ="SELECT id FROM volleyupload ORDER BY id ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $id = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $path = "uploads/$id.doc";

    $actualpath = "http://10.0.2.2/VolleyUpload/$path";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO volleyupload (photo,name) VALUES ('$actualpath','$name')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Here is Java code

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("file/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

I called asynTask on upload button.

```
if (v == buttonUpload) {
        // uploadImage();
        new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();
    }
```

A function calls in doInBackground is

```
private void postFile() {
    try {

        // the file to be posted
         String textFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
         + "/Woodenstreet Doc.doc";
         Log.v(TAG, "textFile: " + textFile);

        // the URL where the file will be posted
        String postReceiverUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/VolleyUpload/upload.php";
        Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

        // new HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // post header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        File file = new File(filePath.toString());
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {

            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " + responseStr);

            // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based
            // on the response
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The exception I get is that

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.topnet999.android.filemanager/storage/0F02-250A/test.doc: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

There is file in emulator - test.doc.
Is there is any thing I miss in code, please help me.
Or suggest a tutorial to upload pdf to php server.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Down vote for what, explain please.

Comment: which part do you feel is not working - the php or the java?

Comment: I don't know where i make mistake, some time file is send to server but it was empty file.

Comment: It looks like you are simply creating a file using `file_put_contents` - there is none of the usuaal php associated with uploading files that I can see

Comment: In my code i get select a file which was place in mobile, now i have to sent this file to php server. I did it, file was empty.

Comment: There seems to be some ambiguity with your code and question. The PHP is looking for `image`, the Java code references and suggests an image upload `Select Picture` or `PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST` but your question states that there is a file called `test.doc` but you want to know how to upload a `pdf`?.... confused!

Comment: Okay, Forget everything that write above.

I want to do that is, I have to upload a text or a PDF or a doc file to PHP server, now please tell me how i do that. Do you have any reference tutorial or example.

Comment: That problem resolve..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution of my question: - 
Here is code of php file - file.php

```
<?php

// DISPLAY FILE INFORMATION JUST TO CHECK IF FILE OR IMAGE EXIST
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';

// DISPLAY POST DATA JUST TO CHECK IF THE STRING DATA EXIST
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

$file_path = "images/";
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {

    echo "file saved success";


} else{

   echo "failed to save file";
}?>
```

Put this file in htdoc folder of Xampp inside test named folder (if there is test folder already then ok, otherwise make a folder named "test"). And also create a folder named "images", in which uploaded file was saved.

Create function to select file from gallery

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                1);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Inside onActivityResult function

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedFileURI = data.getData();
            File file = new File(selectedFileURI.getPath().toString());
            Log.d("", "File : " + file.getName());
            uploadedFileName = file.getName().toString();
            tokens = new StringTokenizer(uploadedFileName, ":");
            first = tokens.nextToken();
            file_1 = tokens.nextToken().trim();
            txt_file_name_1.setText(file_1);
        }
    }
```

This is asyncTask to upload file to server,

```
public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        showDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://10.0.2.2/test/file.php");

            file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    file_1);
            fileBody1 = new FileBody(file1);

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("file1", fileBody1);

            httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {
                final String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)
                        .trim();
                Log.v(TAG, "Response: " + responseStr);

            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        hideDialog();
        Log.e("", "RESULT : " + result);

    }
}
```

Call the asyncTask on button click after selecting the file from gallery.

```
btn_upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();

        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you.
Happy To Help and Happy Coding.

Comment: what is first , file1 ,token, ??

Comment: file1 is File , token is StringTokenizer to split string, First is string in which first string save come after splitting string

Comment: and use Httpurlconnection because httpclient is depriciated

Comment: Project is not here, it just answer.

Comment: what if we use volley? Shane

Comment: Try to encode image into Base64 string and at server side decode this Base64 string into respectively format.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not tested ( as is ) but is generally how one might handle the file upload - there is, as you will see, a debug statement in there. Try to send the file and see what you get ~ if all lokks ok, comment out that line and keep your fingers crossed.

```
   <?php
        /* Basic file upload handler - untested */
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_FILES['image'] ) && !empty( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) ){

            /* Assuming the field being POSTed is called `image`*/
            $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            $tmp  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


            /* debug:comment out if this looks ok */
            exit( print_r( $_FILES,true ) );

            $result = $status = false;

            $basename=pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_FILENAME );


            $filepath='http://10.0.2.2/VolleyUpload/'.$basename;

            $result=@move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $filepath );

            if( $result ){
                $sql = "insert into `volleyupload` ( `photo`, `name` ) values ( '$filepath', '$basename' )";
                $status=mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
            }

            echo $result && $status ? 'File uploaded and logged to db' : 'Something not quite right. Uploaded:'.$result.' Logged:'.$status;
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  
content:/com.topnet999.android.filemanager/storage/0F02-250A/test.doc:
open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What you have is a content provider path. Not a file system path.
So you cannot use the File... classes.

Instead use

```
  InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

For the rest your php code does not make sense as there is no base64 encoding at upload. Further the $path and $actualpath parameters are not used and confusing. And you did not tell what your script should do.