# How to open doc/xls/ppt/pdf/dwg in a App?

Tags: android

i want to open some Common file such as doc/xls/ppt/pdf/dwg,but i can't find a view which can do this,common view  just only open one or two type file.What third can help me to do this. Android :)

Comment: Use my answer for help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820723/upload-doc-pdf-xls-etc-from-android-application-to-php-server

Comment: you can use webview also

Comment: i try to uese webview open a pdf,but there are nothing in UI just blank

Comment: show your webview code

Comment: Thank you for your help! They modify requirements.

Answer (score 0):

to open doc file you can use follow

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



     @Override

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



      Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPressMe);



      button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override

       public void onClick(View v) {



        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),

          "Help Desk Voice Flow.doc");



        try {

         if (file.exists()) {

          Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

          Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

          // replace "application/msword" with

          // "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

          // for docx files

          // objIntent.setDataAndType(path,"application/msword");

          objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

          startActivity(objIntent);

         } else {

          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File NotFound",

            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,

           "No Viewer Application Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)

           .show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

         e.printStackTrace();

        }

       }

      });



     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but i have to  open all the type file by one way.