# How to upload a PDF file to server in android?

Tags: android, pdf, server, file-manager

I referred some previously asked questions but not get proper solution.I am creating an Application and want to send PDF file by selecting it from File Manager.

Thanks any type of help would appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please upload what you have tried till now.

Comment: there is no diffecence, which type of file it is. All files can be sent same way regardless of is that a PDF or MP3 or ZIP file. No difference. So do you want to know `how to upload a file to the server`?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820723/upload-doc-pdf-xls-etc-from-android-application-to-php-server) approach. I think it should work for any file type.

Comment: Thank you. I got it and uploaded the PDF successfully @VladMatvienko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only you have to change this lines of code when you have to select PDF file from gallery .
**intent.setType("application/pdf")**
this will search only PDF files from gallery.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PDF);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Okhttp  [library](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) like this, it is the simplest way to do it. But You have to change your server(API or PHP) code according to this.

```
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("variable", fileName1,
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(fileType1), file))
            .addFormDataPart("key", "")


            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("server url goes here").post(requestBody).build();
    okhttp3.Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Registration Error" + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {

            try {
                String resp = response.body().string();
                Log.v("Docs", resp);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception caught" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    });
```