# Null reference when choosing a pdf file to send to server

Tags: android, pdf

When i choose a PDF file from my device's folders, I keep getting a null reference no matter the path I set it to, I have no idea what is causing this null reference so I need help.
I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133076/how-to-upload-a-pdf-file-to-server-in-android) to pick the PDF file from the device, but it does not show how to send to the server.

The following is my code.

```
public void btnOtherFilesOnClick(View v){
    int PDF = 1;
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setType("application/pdf");
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Pdf"), PDF);
    btnNo = 6;
}

else if (btnNo == 6 ) {
            // File downloads = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageState()));
            //create new file directory object
            //File downloads = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            cursor.close();
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            file = new File(picturePath);
            copyDatabaseToSD();
            createServerPDFStorage();
```

my picturePath keeps being null even though my `filePathColumn[0]` is not. I'm trying to send the PDF to SQLite server.

Comment: try to change your setType to this one `intent.setType("image/*|application/pdf|audio/*");`

Comment: just tried, that makes me unable to choose pdf files @Orvenito