# How to upload files like video audio PDF doc text file image from android to php server

Tags: android, pdf, video, file-upload, android-volley

Hi am working on a chat application and now i want to integrate share audio image PDF video from my application . and i am using this code but its not working properly. do anyone have any idea how to send these files using volley or retrofit. Hear is the which i tried.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And this is my on onActivityResult method.

```
     @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
  data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
                ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
                mime = cr.getType(uri);
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,mime,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString()+"   "+mime);
                // Get the path

                if(mime.equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg")){
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                        uploadImage();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    FileInputStream fis;
                    try {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(new File(uri.getPath()));
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int n;
                        while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                            baos.write(buf, 0, n);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    filebytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    uploadImage();

                }

            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And this is my upload method.

```
     private void uploadImage(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
    UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                        String message = jsonObject.getString("result");
                        sendfileMessage(message);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    Log.d("image path",s);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();


                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Converting Bitmap to String




            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Adding parameters
            params.put("mkey", "R09fQ2hhdC0z");


            if(mime.equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg")){
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
                params.put("ch_img", image);
            }else{
                String image = new String(filebytes);
                params.put("ch_img", image);
            }
            //returning parameters
            Log.d("imagedemo",params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload doc, pdf,xls etc, from android application to php server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820723/upload-doc-pdf-xls-etc-from-android-application-to-php-server)

Comment: @SripadRas is it work for video and audio also

Comment: I guess it should work.

Comment: this is deprecated any other way

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files to API with Mutipart Data.

Create an interface if you are using Retrofit like -

```
@Multipart
@POST("updateProfile")
Call<JsonObject> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Then create Mutipart Data :

```
private MultipartBody.Part getFilePart(String filePath) {

   File fileToUpload=new File(filePath);

   return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileToUpload.getName(),fileToUpload);
    }
```

At last just call the API

```
retrofitObject.uploadFile(getFilePart("filePath").enqueue(this);
```

Comment: so we need only file path to upload video pdf etc.

Comment: Yes only path. But your api must consume Mutipart data.

Comment: after searching hole day count get better way to do this . can you please put a brief code . from onactivityresult . sorry but i stuck on this.